# Email header shows "received from 127.0.0.1"

Tags: ruby, smtp, debian, host, blocked

I hang on this problem for weeks now...

I send mails from my server (debian 8 over ruby 1.8.7 NET::SMTP) over a another smtp server.

A sent email have the following header

```
Return-Path: <sender@mail.com>
Received: from XXXDOMAIN ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]) by
 XXX MAILSERVER
 17:13:40 +0100
Received: from 127.0.0.1 (REALDOMAIN [REALIP]) by
 REALMAILSERVERDOMAIN
 Tue, 15 Mar 2016 16:13:38 +0000
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 17:13:37 +0100
From: admin <sender@mail.com>
To: recepient@mail.com
```

The server gets blocked by the cbl, because of the 127.0.0.1.
REAL PROBLEM FROM CBL: The listing of this IP is because it HELOs as 127.0.0.1

If I make a EHLO over telnet everything is ok, but if I send a mail from ruby, I get the wrong header.

My /etc/hosts:

```
# nameserver config
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 jupiter
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  jupiter.domain.com jupiter
#
# IPv6
xxx     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
xxx ip6-localnet
xxx ip6-mcastprefix
xxx ip6-allnodes
xxx ip6-allrouters
xxx ip6-allhosts
xxxipv6stringxxx  jupiter
```

It would be great, if you have a solution for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...

In ruby you set the domain and we set it to '127.0.0.1'....

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => $config[:mail_smtp_host],
    :port => $config[:mail_smtp_port].to_s,
    :user_name => $config[:mail_smtp_username],
    :password => $config[:mail_smtp_password],
    :authentication => $config[:mail_smtp_authtype],
    :domain => $config[:mail_smtp_domain]  ## HERE must be the domain
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably CBL is blocking `127.0.0.1` (localhost) IP address. Set up your SMTP server so that it sets correct IP address, not localhost.

We have encountered this problem many times and the first thing you want to do is make sure you are not sending your mails from localhost. If you want to increase your mail "whitelistness", you may want to consider adding `SPF`, `DKIM` and `PTR` records.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) The problem is, the smtp is not our server, it's a server from a customer. I alredy told them, they should check their config. They told me the following:

The received from address (127.0.0.1 (REALDOMAIN [REALIP]) is what we are getting from the sending server when it begins the communication with us so it is something that is set on their end. It is how it introduces itself to us in the EHLO part of the SMTP communication.